# Inertia vue2 multiple form in one page

Tags: vuejs2, inertiajs

I have multiple form in one page

```html
    <form name="organizations" @submit.prevent="update">
        <text-input v-model="form.organization_name" 
            :error="form.errors.organization_name" 
            class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/4" label="Customer Name" />
    </form>
    <form v-for="contact in organization.contacts" 
       :name="contact.id" @submit.prevent="update">
        <text-input v-model="contact.first_name"
           class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full" label="First name" />
    </form>
```

How to submit each form using inertia form

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. One is multiple forms on one page using Iniertia JS. The other is dynamic form generation of the second form. I don't think you can do what you want by just addressing the first issue. I believe the second issue will achieve what you want, whereas the answer to the first issue does technically answer the question.

The first issue: Multiple forms on the same page can be solved by using the Form Helper from Inertia JS at [https://inertiajs.com/forms][1]. There are examples for both Vue 2 and Vue 3. Then create two form objects in your script. In your code, change the @sumbit.prevent part to add the URL for each post. See the script entry in the full code below.

```
@submit.prevent="form.post('/update_organization')

@submit.prevent="form2.post('/update_contact')
```

To adapt it to your code:

```
<form name="organizations" @submit.prevent="form.post('/update_organization')">
    <text-input v-model="form.organization_name" 
        :error="form.errors.organization_name" 
        class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/4" label="Customer Name" />
</form>
<form v-for="contact in organization.contacts" 
   :name="contact.id" @submit.prevent="form2.post('/update_contact')">
    <text-input v-model="contact.first_name"
       class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full" label="First name" />
</form>


<script>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue2'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: useForm({
        organization_name: null,
      }),
      form2: useForm({
        first_name: null,
      }),
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The second issue: After submitting this as my answer, I noticed the "v-for" loop in the second form. The easiest way to solve this problem would be to create a child component for the user form and loop through it. This would provide the cleanest code and would make the best use out of both Inertia JS and Vue.

The code might look something like:

For the parent component:

```
<template>

<form name="organizations" @submit.prevent="form.post('/update_organization')">
    <text-input v-model="form.organization_name" 
        :error="form.errors.organization_name" 
        class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/4" label="Customer Name" />
</form>

<!-- the child component -->
<ContactForm v-for="contact in organization.contacts" :contact="contact" />

</template>

<script>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue2'
import { ContactForm } from './ContactForm.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: useForm({
        organization_name: null,
      }),
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

For the child component:

```
<template>

<form name="contact" @submit.prevent="form.post('/update_contact')">
    <text-input v-model="form.name" 
        :error="form.errors.organization_name" 
        class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/4" label="Customer Name" />
</form>

</template>

<script>
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue2'

export default {
  props: {
     contact: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: useForm({
        name: this.contact.name,
      }),
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Note: you might want to emit results back up to the parent after form submission, depending on what you want to do.

I hope this helps.